# Trigger Gitlab CI pipeline only when subproject pipelines are finished

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have 1 question regarding Gitlab pipeline triggering. We have multiple gitlab projects which trigger 1 common project. They are doing It separately. The idea is to trigger this project only when subprojects are finished. Is there are any way to do It better than create script which checks pipeline status via API? Because didn't find any out-of-the box solution for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [trigger:strategy](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#triggerstrategy). As per the docs:

> Use `trigger:strategy` to force the trigger job to wait for the downstream pipeline to complete before it is marked as success.

So say you have build and test stages, and you want the trigger job in the build stage to succeed before moving on to the test stage, you could do something like this: =

```
downstream-build:
  stage: build
  trigger:
    include: path/to/child-pipeline.yml
    strategy: depend
```